# Maintain Order of multiple JobServices scheduled through JobScheduler

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, jobservice

When using JobScheduler to schedule JobServices, if you queue up multiple jobs how does the order of execution get decided?

For instance if JobSerivces get scheduled 1, 2, 3 in that order with the same requirements, what is the logic behind the OS picking which one to do first when those requirements are met?

In my app I've seen the jobTags scheduled 1,2,3,4,5,6 in order and when network finally is available they executed 4,3,6,1,5. Not sure what logic that is but would like to know more if anyone has some insight. I couldn't find anything in the documentation or the several articles there are out there for job scheduling.